# Better way to optimize the linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have written a linq query in c# application to get the name of the application the auth user belongs to

```
var authApplicationRepository = AuthApplicationRepository.GetAllAsList();
var authUserRepository = AuthUserRepository.GetAllAsList();
```

Do you think there is better and shorter way to combine these two lines

```
//Get the name of the application the auth user belongs to
var authUserApplicationId = authUserRepository
                            .Where(x => x.Id == userChangeRequest.AuthUserId)
                            .Select(x => x.ApplicationId)
                            .FirstOrDefault();

var authUserApplicationName = authApplicationRepository
                              .Where(x => x.Id == authUserApplicationId)
                              .Select(x => x.Description)
                              .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You can go further than that, and do `authUserRepository.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == userChangeRequest.AuthUserId)?.ApplicationId`

Comment: How does this give me authUserApplicationName

Comment: You still need 2 linq queries there, but each is shorter.

Comment: You can probably reduce it to one query with a join, but I'm not sure you gain much.

Comment: `var authUserApplicationName = authApplicationRepository.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == authUserRepository.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userChangeRequest.AuthUserId))?.Description;` Please note that you don't gain much here..

Comment: What type are `...repository` variables returned by "GetAll..." methods? `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable`? If you unable to "join" user and application in repository layer you can return `Dictionary` and find required applicationId and corresponding description by only O(1) operations.